# Flatten JSON-response

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, flatten

I have issues with flattening this JSON due to the ending of it which I actually don't need so I could potentially remove it (before or after flattern the JSON). I would like to do this in Python and have tried json_normalized and Panda for export to CSV.

What's special, the last three items, TotalNumberOfMunicipalities, TotalCitizens, Aggregations, lies outside the part I would like to export to CSV after flattern.

JSON:

```
{
    "Municipalities": [
        {
            "Name": "Stockholm",
            "NumberOfCitizens": 974073,
            "Id": "5203d2be-7cda-4caf-9fb5",
            "Attributes": [],
            "Location": {
                "Lat": 59.33,
                "Lon": 18.06
            },
            "PoliticalGovernance": 1
        },
        {
            "Name": "Uppsala",
            "NumerOfCitizens": 230767,
            "Id": "d155e5f5-b94a-4d0e-ba80",
            "Attributes": [],
            "Location": {
                "Lat": 59.86,
                "Lon": 17.64
            },
            "PoliticalGovernance": 3
        }
    ],
    "TotalNumberOfMunicipalities": 33,
    "TotalCitizens": 4000000,
    "Aggregations": {}
}
```

How I would like the output to be
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
df = pd.json_normalize(d, 'Municipalities')
print (df)
        Name  NumberOfCitizens                       Id Attributes  \
0  Stockholm            974073  5203d2be-7cda-4caf-9fb5         []   
1    Uppsala            230767  d155e5f5-b94a-4d0e-ba80         []   

   PoliticalGovernance  Location.Lat  Location.Lon  
0                    1         59.33         18.06  
1                    3         59.86         17.64
```